# Memory warning while loading above 100 images from specific album of photo library

Tags: iphone, uiimage, alassetslibrary, assets

Please find the below code for fetching images from Photo library

```
- (void) initilizeAssetForPhotoLibrary {

if (!assets) {
    assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} else {
    [assets removeAllObjects];
}

ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

    if (result) {
        [assets addObject:result];
    }
};

ALAssetsFilter *onlyPhotosFilter = [ALAssetsFilter allPhotos];
[assetsGroup setAssetsFilter:onlyPhotosFilter];
[assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetsEnumerationBlock];
```

}

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getImagesFromPhotoLibrary {


for(int i=0; i<assets.count; i++) {

ALAsset *asset = [assets objectAtIndex:i];

ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];    
UIImage *getImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRepresentation fullScreenImage] scale:[assetRepresentation scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[assetRepresentation orientation]];
[arrImages addObject:getImage];
}

return arrImages;
```

}

Actually my requirement is that I need to load all image from specific album in application for creating the slideshow.

When I am loading less than 100 images then it works fine but above it gets memory warning and after that it crashed.

Please help me if anyone has different idea to load images and less memory consumption. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: why don't you relase the getImage after adding in arrImages?? have you used ARC???

Comment: @NiravPatel : I have used ARC in application.

Comment: is it working my friend???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep all the images in memory will not do, there is just not enough memory for this.

You will need to fill the array with the `ALAssetRepresentation` of the images and load the image only when you are ready to display it. This way you will only have the image in memory that you are really displaying.

Answer (score -1):

then write down below code and let me know it is working or not!!!

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {

     for(int i=0; i<assets.count; i++) {

    ALAsset *asset = [assets objectAtIndex:i];

    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];    
    UIImage *getImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRepresentation fullScreenImage] scale:[assetRepresentation scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[assetRepresentation orientation]];
   [arrImages addObject:getImage];
 }
  return arrImages;

});
```

Happy Coding...!!!!

Comment: The `arrImages` is returned before the async method is finished. This will not work or you will get cross thread error.